# Neutron diffusion equation (Laplacian, Second order differential equation)

Tags: differential-equations, laplacian

I am trying to use python to solve a neutron diffusion equation. I know the analitical solution. I have a problem in writing the equation in python language.

I dont know how to add a Laplacian to the equation.This is the equation i should write in python. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLeer.png). This is what I have now, i should add a Laplacian  here.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWpLL.png).
Belwo is my code: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2E8or.png)

Comment: Please post code as text, not a link to an image of text.

Comment: r = sp.symbols('r')
y = sp.Function('y')
F = sp.Function('F')
L = sp.symbols('L')

equation=sp.Eq(F(r).diff(r), -1/(L**2) * F(r))

solution = sp.dsolve(equation)

Comment: Please add information to the question text. Use comments for discussions about the changes to the question. What does the second equation have to do with the first? Are there boundary conditions in addition to the equation, minimally that Phi has finite value/limit at r=0 and at infinity? This equation has connections to equations of the Bessel type, did you try WolframAlpha?